# Change the origin when resizing and moving an image

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I am trying to make an image resizer and cropper, but am having trouble with resizing it from a desired point.

Currently, you can resize (just changing the with+height of an `<img>` element) and move around the image (offsetting the top and left margins of the `<img>` element). The problem is once you move it and resize it again, it does so from the center of the image. I would like it to resize relative to the center of the crop window.

Here is an image of what I currently have (top) and what it should be like (bottom):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCny2.jpg

I have been unable to figure out the math of how to resize it and then move it so the origin is not in the center of the image, but in the center of the red window.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially scaling an individual point inside the image (the center of the crop box) by the given scale factor, which involves multiplying each of the coordinates of the point by that factor.

```
new_center_x = old_center_x * new_image_width/old_image_width
new_center_y = old_center_y * new_image_height/old_image_height
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jDXHz/5/

You can then shift both the image and the box back by the difference between the new and old position to keep the box stationary while the image scales around it.